# I cannot deploy node.js to Heroku due to a mysterious error

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, heroku

```
C:\Users\Archie Jugdersuren\summaproject_trial3 - Copy 6 - heroku2>git push 
heroku master
Counting objects: 3247, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3049/3049), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3247/3247), 3.88 MiB | 496.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3247 (delta 811), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 20, column 3
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 20, column 3
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 20, column 3
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot 
common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-
deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to summ2.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/summ2.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/summ2.git'
```

I have tried everything. Here is the strange part on line 20 column 3 there is nothing wrong with it!!! I even got rid of the original line to see if the error still persist and it did. In addition, I got rid of the whole entire package.json file and it still pointed to line 20 column 3 even when package.json was empty. I have uninstall and reinstalled Heroku and no luck... I have doubled checked my dependencies

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.17.2",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "debug": "2.6.3",
    "ejs": "2.5.6",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "google": "2.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "morgan": "1.8.1",
    "request": "2.81.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Mongols/Deploy-Node-To-Heroku.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a second package.json somewhere? Sounds like, since you have the same error with an empty file.

Comment: I see here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/3JsYz

Comment: I do not think there is a second package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you recommit your changes before pushing to heroku? Most answers regarding this question are a result of a missing or extra comma somewhere, I suggest putting your code through a json parser and checking to make sure you have all valid json.

Comment: How do you recommit my changes before pushing to heroku?

Comment: If you set your remote to heroku, you use the regular git workflow of
git add -A
git commit -m "your message here"
git push heroku master

Comment: they should be separate lines. I'm assuming you actually have this set up on git.

Comment: I have recommitted and the same error with the same line 20 column 3 is still persisting